# get value from dict

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have following json response.

```
{
        bufferTime = 15;
        cutOffTime = "02:00";
        shiftId = 1;
        shiftTime = "07:00";
        tripType = PICKUP;
    },
        {
        bufferTime = 15;
        cutOffTime = "02:00";
        shiftId = 2;
        shiftTime = "09:00";
        tripType = PICKUP;
    },
```

And i use the following to store the response in NSMutable arrays.

```
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                        NSDictionary *dict = [res objectAtIndex:i];
                        [shiftIdArray addObject: [dict objectForKey:@"shiftId"]];
                        [shiftTimeArray addObject: [dict objectForKey:@"shiftTime"]];
                        [cutOffTimeArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"cutOffTime"]];
                        //NSLog(@"dict : %@",dict);
                    }
    self.dpShiftTimePicker = [[DownPicker alloc] initWithTextField:self.txtShiftTime withData:shiftTimeArray];
                    [self.dpShiftTimePicker addTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(dp_Selected2:)
                                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }

-(void)dp_Selected2:(id)dp{
    NSString* selectedValue = [self.dpShiftTimePicker text];
    NSLog(@"selectedValue: %@",selectedValue);
}
```

I pass the **shiftTimeArray** in my picker which I made programatically. Now, upon selecting a particular **shiftTime** for e.g **09:00** i want to get it's corresponding **shiftId** and **cutOffTime** and store in a string. Kindly, help.

Comment: where u select the shift time in tableview or else

Comment: already you have array of dictionary then why u innecssary expand with array.

Comment: I added the remaining code.
NSLog(@"selectedValue: %@",selectedValue); gives the shiftTime which I selected.

Comment: It's much easier you pass the index of the selected item to the *action method*, or make it easily available.  Then you have your array indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
- (void)dp_Selected2:(id)dp
{
     NSString* selectedValue = [self.dpShiftTimePicker text];

     NSString* selectedIDValue =  [shiftIdArray objectAtIndex:[shiftTimeArray indexOfObject:selectedValue]];

     NSString* selectedCutOFFValue  = [cutOffTimeArray objectAtIndex:[shiftTimeArray indexOfObject:selectedValue]];

     NSLog(@"selectedValue: %@",selectedValue);
 }
```

Comment: Happy to help you dear:)